# How do I correctly auto fit an excel file column with a function

Tags: python, pandas.excelwriter

I am trying to autofit my excel ws columns with the following function:

```
def autoFit(ExcelWriter,SheetName,DF):
    for column in DF:
        print(column)
        column_length = max(DF[column].astype(str).map(len).max(), len(column))
        col_idx = DF.columns.get_loc(column)
        ExcelWriter.sheets[SheetName].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_length)
    return 1
```

and then I call it like below :

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Blabla.xlsx", engine = 'xlsxwriter')    
autoFit(writer,'TEST',MYDF)
writer.save()
```

but when I open excel file, the columns are not fitted, what am I doing wrong there ?

Comment: Do you mean that no values are written to the sheet at all? Or are the wrong values written? Do you see the `print(column)` output?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I mean that : Values are written and print(column) does print columns names but the columns in excel aren't fitted (some columns width are to small)

Comment: Oh, so by "fit" you mean to change the graphical column width, not to do a numerical fit of the values to some model function?!

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes, i try to adjust column width dynamically

Comment: I don't know if this is possible at all. It depends on the font and the font size, and your Python program doesn't have access to that, I guess.

Comment: I think you are looking for https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html Just use this with pandas and you can style your excel with proper style and borders.